# Sound issue after reinstalling Xubuntu

Tags: sound, xubuntu, 18.04, pulseaudio, soundcard

So basically I have a very old PC with an onboard-soundcard.

After installing xubuntu 18.04 the sound had worked perfectly fine. Now after I've had to reinstall xubuntu, the sound stopped working (it told me that some parts of the operating system might not have been installed properly)

All I see is described in [this article](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/). Just a dummy output channel.

I've tried the first two methods. All that it is showing me is

> Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
>
> Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).

Then I've tried the third method, but "RUN=no" was already there by deafult.

What else can I try? Also, I am not an expert, so please write an answer that is easy-to-follow.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem after a recent update on Debian and I managed to fix it by un-commenting the line `load-module module-alsa-sink` on the `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file. This is definitely a bug as the `module-udev-detect` Pulseaudio module should handle this... but, regardless the workaround works fine, until they figure out what's wrong with the detection module. For some reason Pulseaudio was falling back to the "Dummy output" sink (AKA null sink) instead of providing a default sink to the card it did manage to find...

For reference sake I'm using a HDA ATI SB card on a Realtek ALC887-VD chip on an old M5A78L-M LX/BR ASUS motherboard. Hope this information helps others with the same issue until a fix lands on the respective package(s)!

EDIT: probably unnecessary but it doesn't hurt to remove the directory `~/.config/pulse/` (or `~/.pulse/`). It will be regenerated  onthe next PA run.